# socket operation on non socket : error while setting socket options and binding socket

Tags: c, sockets

when run, the program gives out

socket operation on non socket: error while binding socket.

After that when I used `setsockopt()`
it again gives me error:

```
socket operation on non socket, error while setting options to socket.
```

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04. Is there a problem in the 
operating system or my code? (since i have seen the port i am using 
here was not in use by any other program and I have tried changing
port number to 10000 and in range of 56000 also)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>               
#include<sys/socket.h>      
#include<netinet/in.h>      
#include<arpa/inet.h>       
#include<errno.h>           

#define PORT 7890

int main()
{
    int sock_fd, new_sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in host_addr, client_addr;              
    socklen_t sin_size;
    int recv_length, yes = 1;
    char buffer[1024];                                      


    if(sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == -1)     
    {
        perror("in creating socket \n");
        exit(-1);
    }   
    else
        printf("Socket: SUCCESS \n");

    if(setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,sizeof(int)) == -1)
        perror("while setting socket option SO_REUSEADDR \n");
    else
        printf("Socket Option: SUCCESS \n");



    host_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;             
    host_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);           
    host_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;               
    memset(&(host_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);     




    if(bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&host_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
        perror("while binding \n");
    else
        printf("Binding: SUCCESS \n");  


    if(listen(sock_fd, 5) == -1)
        perror("while listening \n");
    else
        printf("Listen: SUCCESS \n");   


    while(1)
    {

        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        new_sockfd = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &sin_size);

            if(new_sockfd == -1)
            {
                perror("failed to accept \n");
                exit(-1);   
            }   
            else
                printf("accept: SUCCESS \n");
            printf("Server got connction from IP ADDRESS: %s, PORT NUMBER:%d \n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
    send(new_sockfd, "HELLO BASTARDS !\n", 16, 0);

        recv_length = recv(new_sockfd, &buffer, 1024, 0);

            while(recv_length > 0)
            {
                printf("Recieved %d Bytes \n", recv_length );



                recv_length = recv(new_sockfd, &buffer, 1024, 0);                       
            }

        close(new_sockfd);  
    }




return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `if(sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == -1) `  does not do what you expect. Mind the operator precedence. `==` binds tighter than `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Usual operator precedence problem:

```
if(sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == -1)
```

should be

```
if((sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
```

Comment: Why is this mistake made over, and over, and over again in networking code?   Why are they fascinated with compound boolean expressions that go wrong?   Are devs just too lazy to use two lines that can then be easily debugged?   Baffles me:(